# How do I get BeautifulSoup to show me specific strings?

Tags: xml, beautifulsoup, stanford-nlp

My XML document structure is like this:

`root
   document
       sentences
           sentence id
               tokens
                   token id
                      word
                      lemma
                      POS
                      NER`

Here is an example of the children of `token id`:

```
        <word>Denmark</word>
        <lemma>denmark</lemma>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>0</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>7</CharacterOffsetEnd>
        <POS>NN</POS>
        <NER>LOCATION</NER>
```

I want to filter out details of only those words that have the NER tag "LOCATION". I tried this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup,"lxml-xml")
print(soup.find_all('NER'))
```

But this gives me:

```
[<NER>LOCATION</NER>, <NER>O</NER>, <NER>NUMBER</NER>, <NER>O</NER>]
```

I want:

```
denmark, LOCATION
```

How do I get that? I looked into the documentation but I cannot find a way out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to locate the `NER` tags with `LOCATION` text and get to it's parent:

```
for ner in soup('NER', text='LOCATION'):
    token = ner.parent

    print(token.word.get_text(), token.ner.get_text())
```